Ubuntu 24.04 and NVIDIA keep causing issues with external monitor
Problem: in Ubuntu 24.04, now and then there is an update which bricks the ability to use an external monitor properly.
I have no idea what else I can do to further debug or change in configurations to get the system to handle the external monitor properly.
Below I share system details, debug messages and configuration files. Any help is welcome.
I have tried KDE Plasma, GNOME, Ubuntu, Ubuntu on Wayland and the problem happens on all those.
I have an NVIDIA GPU, no integrated CPU graphics card.
If I connect via HDMI, the monitor gets recognized but the screen stays black.
When I connect via a Thunderbolt port, there is image but it appears with the lowest resolution: 640x480.
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 around June.
I originally got it to work (if I am not mistaken) by trying out different NVIDIA driver versions.
Another problem that was occurring in parallel to this was the inability to use Night Light.
Whenever Night Light would not work, neither would the external monitor.
For a while, what solved this was to logout after logging in, and logging back in.
But this has stopped being a solution.
I even locked up the NVIDIA driver version against unattended upgrades by editing the /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades file:
// Added this part.
// Python regular expressions, matching packages to exclude from upgrading
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
    "nvidia-";
    "libnvidia-";
    "linux-modules-nvidia-";
    "linux-objects-nvidia-";
    "linux-signatures-nvidia-";
    "xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-";

Ever since I added this, the NVIDIA drivers would not be updated into something that would inevitably break my external monitor usage.
This allowed me to continue updating the system with the software updater without losing external monitor functionality.
I made no changes to the system directly or in an aware way, but on the 7th of August 2024 when I booted the system, it hanged with a black screen for quite a while.
I turned it off manually and turned back on.
It booted, but the external monitor woes are back.
Disclaimer:

The monitor and the cable are not damaged. I've tried multiple cables too.
I have tried multiple NVIDIA driver versions, and each time I tried doing a complete removal and complete reinstallation. Nothing worked.

NVIDIA driver reinstallation procedure I followed:
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^cuda-.*'
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^libcuda.*'
sudo apt-get remove --purge 'nvidia-cuda-*'

sudo apt-get update

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-modules-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)

sudo update-initramfs -u

The image below is from the GNOME Settings 46.0.1.
You can see the second display is identified as "Nvidia" rather than the actual external monitor.

If we inspect "Nvidia", we see that it is set to the lowest possible resolution 640x480:

If I go into nvidia-settings, the following is shown:

Here are the details of the GPU itself:

If I open the DP-3 (NVIDIA) page, it shows the following:

General system details below:
lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

uname -a

Linux Machine 6.8.0-39-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jul  5 21:49:14 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Display-specific lspci and lshw details:
lspci | grep -i vga

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106BM [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile 6GB] (rev a1)


sudo lshw -C display

  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP106BM [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile 6GB]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:152 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       product: simpledrmdrmfb
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080

xrandr details:
xrandr --query
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  47.99  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected 640x480+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       59.94*+
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

I have no idea what it calls "Screen 0", but the resolution of 2560 is equal to the 1920 of the laptop screen plus the 640 from the external monitor detected as "Nvidia".
NVIDIA configuration and drivers:

NVIDIA-specific nvidia-smi details:
nvidia-smi
Thu Aug  8 11:40:35 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.183.01             Driver Version: 535.183.01   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060        Off | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   52C    P8               5W /  88W |    644MiB /  6144MiB |      3%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2735      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          179MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2989      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         33MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3565      G   ...AAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       13MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

NVIDIA-specific glxinfo details:
glxinfo | grep -i 'device\|vendor\|rendering'
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
    GL_NV_path_rendering, GL_NV_path_rendering_shared_edge, 
    GL_NV_stereo_view_rendering, GL_NV_texgen_reflection, 
    GL_NV_path_rendering, GL_NV_path_rendering_shared_edge, 
    GL_NV_stereo_view_rendering, GL_NV_texgen_reflection, 
    GL_NV_packed_float_linear, GL_NV_path_rendering, 
    GL_NV_path_rendering_shared_edge, GL_NV_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_NV_shadow_samplers_cube, GL_NV_stereo_view_rendering,

Configuration of Xorg:
cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 535.183.01

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes      "1920x1080"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Further debugging below using dmesg:
dmesg | grep -i nvidia

[    3.689241] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input20
[    3.689313] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input21
[    3.689430] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input22
[    3.689503] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input23
[    3.717742] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    3.717748] nvidia: module license taints kernel.
[    3.826288] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 234
[    3.827219] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: VGA decodes changed: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[    4.028722] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  535.183.01  Sun May 12 19:39:15 UTC 2024
[    4.070272] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  535.183.01  Sun May 12 19:31:08 UTC 2024
[    4.094739] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[    5.029363] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[    5.268971] nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
[    5.344647] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 510.
[   12.315422] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   87.488462] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.663032] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.664410] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.665845] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.667183] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.780268] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.781679] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.783027] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.784358] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.898161] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.899738] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.901122] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.902555] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 5351.420711] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 5351.422289] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 5351.423789] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 5351.425333] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

More dmesg details pertaining to the displays:
dmesg | grep -i -e monitor -e display -e hdmi -e dp

[    0.019836] ACPI: RSDP 0x000000005EA67000 000024 (v02 ALASKA)
[    0.235226] CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)
[    0.368258] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [AER PCIeCapability LTR DPC]
[    0.369142] pci 0000:00:00.0: [8086:3ec2] type 00 class 0x060000 conventional PCI endpoint
[    0.369308] pci 0000:00:08.0: [8086:1911] type 00 class 0x088000 conventional PCI endpoint
[    0.369415] pci 0000:00:14.0: [8086:a2af] type 00 class 0x0c0330 conventional PCI endpoint
[    0.370249] pci 0000:00:14.2: [8086:a2b1] type 00 class 0x118000 conventional PCI endpoint
[    0.370426] pci 0000:00:16.0: [8086:a2ba] type 00 class 0x078000 conventional PCI endpoint
[    0.370848] pci 0000:00:17.0: [8086:a282] type 00 class 0x010601 conventional PCI endpoint
[    0.374157] pci 0000:00:1f.0: [8086:a2c9] type 00 class 0x060100 conventional PCI endpoint
[    0.374479] pci 0000:00:1f.2: [8086:a2a1] type 00 class 0x058000 conventional PCI endpoint
[    0.374762] pci 0000:00:1f.3: [8086:a2f0] type 00 class 0x040300 conventional PCI endpoint
[    0.375484] pci 0000:00:1f.4: [8086:a2a3] type 00 class 0x0c0500 conventional PCI endpoint
[    0.375924] pci 0000:01:00.0: [10de:1c60] type 00 class 0x030000 PCIe Endpoint
[    0.376295] pci 0000:01:00.1: [10de:10f1] type 00 class 0x040300 PCIe Endpoint
[    0.381484] pci 0000:6d:00.0: [1969:e0b1] type 00 class 0x020000 PCIe Endpoint
[    0.381931] pci 0000:6e:00.0: [10ec:5250] type 00 class 0x080501 PCIe Endpoint
[    0.382434] pci 0000:6f:00.0: [8086:f1a8] type 00 class 0x010802 PCIe Endpoint
[    0.383020] pci 0000:70:00.0: [8086:24fd] type 00 class 0x028000 PCIe Endpoint
[    0.416068] pci 0000:00:1f.1: [8086:a2a0] type 00 class 0x058000 conventional PCI endpoint
[    0.430459] UDP hash table entries: 32768 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
[    0.430560] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 32768 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
[    0.430665] NET: Registered PF_XDP protocol family
[    0.491771] drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
[    0.861547] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 6.08
[    0.862921] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 6.08
[    1.198092] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.229766] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0461, idProduct=4de3, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    1.472839] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=06cb, idProduct=0078, bcdDevice= 1.54
[    1.739547] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0780, bcdDevice= 1.70
[    1.990695] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b5a7, bcdDevice=36.01
[    2.233764] usb 1-11: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0a2b, bcdDevice= 0.10
[    3.016801] systemd[1]: Created slice system-modprobe.slice - Slice /system/modprobe.
[    3.026973] systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@configfs.service - Load Kernel Module configfs...
[    3.027890] systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@dm_mod.service - Load Kernel Module dm_mod...
[    3.028870] systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@drm.service - Load Kernel Module drm...
[    3.029900] systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@efi_pstore.service - Load Kernel Module efi_pstore...
[    3.030937] systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@fuse.service - Load Kernel Module fuse...
[    3.032133] systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@loop.service - Load Kernel Module loop...
[    3.036433] systemd[1]: Starting systemd-udev-trigger.service - Coldplug All udev Devices...
[    3.060268] systemd[1]: modprobe@configfs.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    3.060393] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@configfs.service - Load Kernel Module configfs.
[    3.060672] systemd[1]: modprobe@dm_mod.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    3.060787] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@dm_mod.service - Load Kernel Module dm_mod.
[    3.061065] systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    3.061170] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@drm.service - Load Kernel Module drm.
[    3.061383] systemd[1]: modprobe@efi_pstore.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    3.061490] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@efi_pstore.service - Load Kernel Module efi_pstore.
[    3.061718] systemd[1]: modprobe@fuse.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    3.061840] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@fuse.service - Load Kernel Module fuse.
[    3.062037] systemd[1]: modprobe@loop.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    3.062135] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@loop.service - Load Kernel Module loop.
[    3.689241] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input20
[    3.689313] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input21
[    3.689430] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input22
[    3.689503] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input23

Error-specific dmesgdetails:
dmesg | grep -i -e nvidia -e monitor -e display -e hdmi -e dp | grep -i error

[   12.315422] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   87.488462] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.663032] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.664410] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.665845] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.667183] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.780268] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.781679] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.783027] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.784358] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.898161] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.899738] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.901122] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   89.902555] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 5351.420711] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 5351.422289] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 5351.423789] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 5351.425333] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

Thank you very much!
